Capacitor: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED An unknown error occurred when fetching the script
I have an issue where I load service-worker with capacitor, it has an error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and in the console An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
Full error:
TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost/') 
with script ('https://localhost/service-worker.js'): 
An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.

Here the script for service worker register:
 <script>
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
          .register("/service-worker.js")
          .then((registration) => {
            console.log(
              "Service Worker registered with scope:",
              registration.scope
            );
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Service Worker registration failed:", error);
          });
      }
    </script>

When I check this on the web browser, it works perfectly but when I run npx cap run android I got the error I mentionned earlier.
Here the result in web browser:

And the result from the inspected webview

Here the repo: https://github.com/radonirinamaminiaina/capacitor-sw
How can I solve this?
Already tried this: PWA + Capacitor.JS: Failed to register a service worker (in Android) but the error change to net::ERR_NAME_RESOLVED
Thank you

By default, capacitor can't access to the service worker which we want to register.
So we need to create a bridge and use shouldInterceptRequest so it can handle the request from our webView entrypoint file.
Here the full solution:
package com.root.app; // Your package name

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import android.webkit.ServiceWorkerClient;
import android.webkit.ServiceWorkerController;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      ServiceWorkerController swController = ServiceWorkerController.getInstance();

      swController.setServiceWorkerClient(new ServiceWorkerClient() {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebResourceRequest request) {
          if (request.getUrl().toString().contains("index.html")) {
            request.getRequestHeaders().put("Accept", "text/html");
          }

          // Access Capacitor's bridge and use its local server to handle the request
          return MainActivity.this.getBridge().getLocalServer().shouldInterceptRequest(request);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

After that, when you run npx cap run android, it should work.
Here a screenshot from chrome://inspect

